# Could anybody Explain the process step by step

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def m():
    return[lambda x:x*i for i in range(4)]
print([m(9) for m in m()])
```

I want step by step execution.

Comment: Use: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: Please take the [tour] (again) and learn [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `m` returns a list of 4 `lambda` functions. Each of these functions takes one argument, `x`, and returns a value computed by taking that value and multiplying it by `i`. The intention may have been for `i` to take on successive values 0, 1, 2 and 3 (produced by the `range` function) for each of these 4 lambda functions respectively. However, these lambda functions do not make copies of `i` when they are created but will use whatever the current value of `i` is when they are invoked. When function `m` returns with the list of the 4 lambda functions, `i` has the final value of `3` from the `range` function. So all 4 lambda functions are identical and will multiply its argument by 3 and return that product as its result.

`[m(9) for m in m()]` is a list comprehension that will create a list where each element is created successively by first calling `m()` and for each value `m` in the list returned, which, as we saw, is a lambda function that multiplies its argument by 3, calls that function with the argument 9 and takes the result (27) and appends it to the new list being created. Thus we end up with a list of 4 elements, all of which are 27, `[27, 27, 27, 27]`, which are then printed out.